DisplayPort routing differential impedance
I need to route DisplayPort differential signals and am wondering what the best differential impedance is. I found this application note by NXP. But it opens up more questions than answers. It gives different values between 100 and 85 ohms. So what is the best value in the end?
The CPU I am working with is the Atom E8000.


So what is your application? From CPU to connector, or something else?

Actually it is a SoM carrier. So SoM connector to DP connector.

So what does the SoM manufacturer data sheets, hardware user guides and application notes say about it? Or SoM manufacturer support team?

What is your target GHz-m  product? Choice of cable? Lower Zo is better if given a choice with thinner substrates.

Who is the SoM manufacturer, what is the model of the SoM board? Can you draw a simple schematic or connections diagram so that we can how you intend to connect them?

@EdinFifić There's no need for any schematic or connection diagram. All lanes are routed lile they should - four high speed differential lanes, with the AUX lanes being a low speed differential lane. This is just about the PCB differential impedance, not how to connect them.

The SoM manufacturer does not have a guide for DP impedance. I will try to contact their support team but they have not been very helpful so far.
